# Diagonal Newton's method for unconstrained optimisation.

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

Assume you are minimising a convex function $f$. The function is twice-differentiable. The well-known Newton's method consists in starting form some point $x_0$ and then using the iteration below.
$$ x_{t+1} = x_{t} - H(x_t)^{-1}g(x_t) $$
Here, H is the Hessian of $f$ and $g$ is the gradient of $f$. The justification for the method is that we are locally approximating the function $f$ near $x_t$ with a second-order polynomial (i.e. a paraboloid) via Taylor's expansion. Newton's method then consists in going straight to the minimum of this paraboloid.

---

The question is this: Is there a way to do this so that the matrix being inverted is diagonal? More specifically, assume we want to approximate the function $f$ at point $x_t$ with a paraboloid which is constrained to be *axis-aligned* (this could or could not be a good approximation, but for now let's stick to it). We would then use the following iteration.
 $$ x_{t+1} = x_{t} - \alpha D_t(x_t)^{-1}g(x_t) $$
Here, $D_t$ is some *diagonal* matrix for which we have (in some sense):
$f(x) \approx f(x_t) + (x - x_t)^\top g(x_t) + \frac12(x - x_t)^\top D_t(x_t) (x - x_t)$ and $\alpha$ is some suitable constant.

---

But how to find $D$?

One would hope that such a method would require less iterations than standard (first-order) gradient descent and more iterations than full Newton's method. But maybe there is some fundamental reason why such a method just doesn't make sense?

Maybe I was searching in the wrong places but the only thing I found in the literature is to use the diagonal of the Hessian as $D$, which for me does not look like it was obviously the best approximation available.

Comment: Using a diagonal matrix is like performing the Newton's method (unidimensional) separately for each coordinate. So its construction is quite straightward.  Sure that generally it will converge more slowly. The conditions for its convergence, instead, I am not able to fix right now.

Comment: @GCab So you are saying just use $D(x_t)_{ii} = H(x_t)_{ii}$. But is there a way to show that using this $D$ is actually the best axis-aligned-paraboloid approximation to $f$ at $x_t$?

Comment: well, that it is a paraboloid comes from using a quadratic approximation, that it is "best axis-aligned" comes from applying the best approximation indipendently for each coordinate.